# How to take pictures from the camera without preview when my app starts?

Tags: android, android-intent

Now all I want is an app that just takes the picture from the camera upon launching. No layout, no camera preview...nothing, just a simple app icon to launch the app. Once launched the camera should take the picture.

Here is the preview image, that **i do not want to appear in my app**. I just want to eanble my app to **click the take picture button encircled in the image** here:

[image]

Once the picture is taken then I need to save it in my photo gallery.

Can someone guide me here? Thanks

Here is some code that I have tried on emulator and device.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Main extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private Camera camera;
     private ImageButton cameraClick;
     private SurfaceHolder mHolder; 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
      mHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
      mHolder.addCallback(this);
      mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);  

      cameraClick = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cameraClick);
      cameraClick.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
            camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback,jpegCallback);
       }
      });  





      }

     // Handles when shutter open
     ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback()
     {
      public void onShutter()
      {   

      }
     };

     /** Handles data for raw picture */
     PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback()
     {
      public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
      {   

      }
     }; 

     /** Handles data for jpeg picture */
     PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback()
    {
      public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
    {
       // we do something using return byte[] of taken image.
      }
     };

     @Override
     public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,int format,int width,int height)
    {

      // Set camera preview size,orientation,rotation using parameters 

    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
             camera.startPreview();       

     }

     @Override
     public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
      camera = Camera.open();
             try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
       }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }

     }

     @Override
     public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
      camera.stopPreview();
             camera.release();
            camera = null; 

     }

}
```

Now I am able to hear the picture click on the button click both on the emulator and the device. Now I want to save the picture as well. Any clue?

Comment: I have looked into the sample code. There is no mention of such a functionality or feature anywhere.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, You just want a single button in whole layout which clicks a photo upon clicking without a preview right?

Comment: @AbhishekV Absolutely correct! This is what i require.

Comment: Then the answer which you have provided should work fine

Comment: @Muhammad Maqsoodur R Use surfaceView behind to any layout which can hide the surfaceView. In your case hide the surfaceview by making your design layout on that surfaceView

Comment: related more complex request: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386025/taking-picture-from-camera-without-preview

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752730/take-a-photo-automatically-without-user-interaction

Answer (score 23):

Use below code. Its Tested and Worked for me. Any issues please feel free to put comments.

```
private void takeSnapShots()
{
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image snapshot   Started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     // here below "this" is activity context.  
 SurfaceView surface = new SurfaceView(this);
    Camera camera = Camera.open();
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surface.getHolder());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    camera.startPreview();
    camera.takePicture(null,null,jpegCallback);
}


 /** picture call back */
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
{
    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
  String dir_path = "";// set your directory path here
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(dir_path+File.separator+image_name+no_pics+".jpg");    
        outStream.write(data);
        outStream.close();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally 
    {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image snapshot Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
    Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
}
};
```

Comment: SurfaceView surface = new SurfaceView(this); gives me a null object reference

Comment: U should use piece of code inside activity, or try to pass activity context

Comment: sorry about the previous comment...actually it is giving null object refrence in this line   camera.setPreviewDisplay(surface.getHolder());

Comment: check which is context is getting passed for surface creation.. please try set activity context.

Comment: The picture rotates by 90 degree clockwise

Comment: Device specific.

Answer (score 13):

As of API-Level 11 the [SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) was added. With it a SurfaceView is no longer needed. I tested the following code with my Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo.

```
mCamera = Camera.open();
try {
    mCamera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(10));
} catch (IOException e1) {
    Log.e(Version.APP_ID, e1.getMessage());
}

Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
params.setPreviewSize(640, 480);
params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
mCamera.setParameters(params);
mCamera.startPreview();
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.i(Version.APP_ID, "picture-taken");
    }
});
```

Comment: `SurfaceTexture` requires `camera.startPreview()` call. And it is pretty the same as `SurfaceView`. So I was not able to escape preview "freezing" with `SurfaceTexture`.

Answer (score 2):

The camera preview is just a special kind of View in your layout, so if you don't want to display it but still use your existing code without a lot of modifications, there are some tricks you can do.

For example, in your layout file where you're adding the camera preview SurfaceView, you can just add another view on top of it to block the preview. That way you'll still be able to use your existing code without modifying too much and the camera preview will work just like it did before, but you'll have the effect you're looking for which is not showing the camera preview.

Comment: but not a great approach from performance point of view. we'll have one extra layer of overdraw which can be avoided if we follow the `SurfaceTexture` way..

Answer (score 1):

I've tried exactly what you need before and after alot of research found out that for some reason you must have a preview started and even showing that content in a SurfaceView to be able to get the picture, apparently the system behind the scenes flushes whatever is in the buffer for the SurfaceView rendering the preview, now what I did to overcome this issue (taking the picture without preview) was just to set the SurfaceView in my layout to 1dp width and 1dp height (notice it has to be 1dp, 0dp will cause a crash).

```
<SurfaceView
   android:layout_width="1dp"
   android:layout_height="1dp"/>
```

It definitely might not be a very elegant way to get rid of the "preview" Image but it definitely does the trick and left me room to do everything else I had in mind.

Hope this helps...

Regards

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for doing the same thing, but with **CAMERA 2 API**, you could check my answer here. [Capture picture without preview using camera2 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003186/capture-picture-without-preview-using-camera2-api/41916280#41916280).