# Capture picture without preview using camera2 API

Tags: android, camera

What I want to achieve is capturing a picture without showing the preview, sending directly the output to an `ImageReader`. 
I have used the [Camera2Basic example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java) as a starting point. 
However, the callback of my `ImageReader` is never called, hence no image is sent to its `Surface`.
Do I really need to display a preview first?

This is the camera code, which is ordered following the flow of the asynchronous callbacks:

```
private ImageReader imageReader;
private Handler backgroundHandler;
private HandlerThread backgroundThread;
private String cameraId;
private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
private CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        setupCamera2();
    }

    private void setupCamera2() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        try {

            for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

            if (characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) != CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                continue;
            }

            this.cameraId = cameraId;

            int[] picSize = Settings.getPictureSize();
            int picWidth = picSize[0];
            int picHeight = picSize[1];

            imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(picWidth, picHeight, ImageFormat.JPEG, 2);
            imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(onImageAvailableListener, backgroundHandler);
            }

        } catch (CameraAccessException | NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void openCamera2() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {

            manager.openCamera(cameraId, cameraStateCallback, backgroundHandler);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback cameraStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice device) {
            cameraDevice = device;
            createCameraCaptureSession();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice cameraDevice) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {}
    };



    private void createCaptureSession() {
        List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new LinkedList<>();
        outputSurfaces.add(imageReader.getSurface());

        try {

            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    cameraCaptureSession = session;
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {}
            }, null);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener onImageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            createCaptureRequest();
        }
    };


    private void createCaptureRequest() {
        try {

            CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            requestBuilder.addTarget(imageReader.getSurface());

            // Focus
            requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

            // Orientation
            int rotation = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));

            cameraCaptureSession.capture(requestBuilder.build(), camera2Callback, null);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever get it working without the preview?

Comment: @KimHJ yes, check my answer below :)

Comment: where did "settings" come from?

Comment: you have some mistake in code. You should close connection with camera after using, or it will be work only once. Added         cameraDevice?.close() in the end of onImageAvailableListener

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should capture photos in "onConfigured" function but not onImageAvailable.

```
public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
            cameraCaptureSession = session;
            createCaptureRequest();
        }
```

In this function "onImageAvailable",you should save images,

```
Image image = mImageReader.acquireLatestImage();
ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
buffer.get(bytes);
try {
    save(bytes, file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
image.close();
```

"onImageAvailable" function will be invoked after session.capture() .

Comment: Thanks, it works. A question a little off topic: what do you think is the best image format for the ImageReader?

Comment: YUV. It's a pain to convert to RGB, but the quality is difficulty to match.

Answer (score 16):

Since I struggled a lot finding out how this works, here is a minimal working Android Service which can process Image data. It probably needs some time after create before you can call start the service, though!

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class VideoProcessingService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "VideoProcessing";
    private static final int CAMERA = CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT;
    private CameraDevice camera;
    private CameraCaptureSession session;
    private ImageReader imageReader;

    private CameraDevice.StateCallback cameraStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            VideoProcessingService.this.camera = camera;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {}
    };

    private CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback sessionStateCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
            VideoProcessingService.this.session = session;
            try {
                session.setRepeatingRequest(createCaptureRequest(), null, null);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e){
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {}
    };

    private ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener onImageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader){
            Image img = reader.acquireLatestImage();
            processImage(img);
            img.close();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            manager.openCamera(getCamera(manager), cameraStateCallback, null);
            imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(320, 240, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 30 * 600); //fps * 10 min
            imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(onImageAvailableListener, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e){
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Return the Camera Id which matches the field CAMERA.
     */
    public String getCamera(CameraManager manager){
        try {
            for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
                int cOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
                if (cOrientation == CAMERA) {
                    return cameraId;
                }
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {
            camera.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(imageReader.getSurface()), sessionStateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e){
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        try {
            session.abortCaptures();
        } catch (CameraAccessException e){
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        session.close();
    }

    /**
     *  Process image data as desired.
     */
    private void processImage(Image image){
        //Process image data
    }

    private CaptureRequest createCaptureRequest() {
        try {
            CaptureRequest.Builder builder = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            builder.addTarget(imageReader.getSurface());
            return builder.build();
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Got an exception `                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice.createCaptureSession(java.util.List, android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession$StateCallback, android.os.Handler)' on a null object reference`

Comment: You don't have to set max images to 30*600, when creating ImageReader. The buffers will be reused. All you have to do is close the image getting from ImageReader.

Comment: Little error there : 
'if (cOrientation == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK) {'
instead of
'if (cOrientation == CAMERA) {'

Comment: @RenaudBlue CAMERA is a constant defined at the top, hwy not just change the value there?

Comment: @iMom0 the service doesn't work as published currently. It assumes onCreate method is called before onStartCommand for a service.  I guess Timon didn't actually test it and posted it from memory.

Comment: @roundsparrowhilltx What am I doing here?

Comment: A year ago, it worked like this :( maybe something changed in the API? But it might also be that I did not consider all cases with state saving, etc.

Comment: Here is a working version of the code https://gist.github.com/RoundSparrow/142b840ca86ba7a46639f23c5c0d195b - it has some extra log output and a few variables renamed.

Answer (score 12):

I've been struggling with CAMERA2 API for a long time, looking for how to take pictures **without preview** from **all available** cameras on the device.

I ended up creating a project on GitHub that does exactly what you want (and maybe more)!
https://github.com/hzitoun/android-camera2-secret-picture-taker

[image]

Hope that helped :)

Comment: Where is the dependency link for that library bro.

Comment: @viper there is no library bro. You just need to copy the CaptureService https://github.com/hzitoun/android-camera2-secret-picture-taker/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/hzitoun/camera2SecretPictureTaker/services

Comment: @hzitoun How can I capture video without preview using Camera2 API?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I had an issue with having a basic preview of the camera in a textureView. I found the best working solution to take a picture, save the picture to external directory and NOT break the preview! Camera2 API was buggy af. Enjoy <3. Also asks for permissions ahead!

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="theandroidguy.bart.keepreceipt">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".Insert_Receipt_Info_Activity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ScanReceipt" />
        <activity
            android:name=".NavigationActivity"
            android:label="KeepReceipt"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

ScanReceipt.java

```
package theandroidguy.bart.keepreceipt;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class ScanReceipt extends AppCompatActivity{

    private Button btnCapture;
    private TextureView textureView;

    public static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE= 1;

    //Check state orientation of output image
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    static{
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0,90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90,0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180,270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270,180);
    }

    private String cameraId;
    private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    private CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
    private Size imageDimension;
    private ImageReader imageReader;

    //Save to FILE
    private File file;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
    private boolean mFlashSupported;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;

    CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice = camera;
            createCameraPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int i) {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_receipt);
        askPermissions();

        textureView = findViewById(R.id.textureView);
        //From Java 1.4 , you can use keyword 'assert' to check expression true or false
        assert textureView != null;
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        btnCapture = findViewById(R.id.snapPictureBtn);
        btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                takePicture();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void takePicture() {
        if(null == cameraDevice) {
            Log.e("No cam", "cameraDevice is null and not being detected!!!");
            return;
        }

        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
            Size[] jpegSizes = null;
            if (characteristics != null) {
                jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
            }
            int width = 640;
            int height = 480;
            if (jpegSizes != null &&
                        0 < jpegSizes.length) {
                width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
            }
            final ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
            List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>(2);
            outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
            //i believe this fucks over the preview after snapping
            //outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));
            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
            // Orientation
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/picture.jpg");
            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                    Image image = null;
                    try {
                        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (image != null) {
                            image.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                    OutputStream output = null;
                    try {
                        output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        output.write(bytes);
                    } finally {
                        if (null != output) {
                            output.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);
            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                    Toast.makeText(ScanReceipt.this, "Saved:" + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    createCameraPreview();
                }
            };
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    try {
                        session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed on config!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void createCameraPreview() {
        try{
            SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(),imageDimension.getHeight());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    if(cameraDevice == null)
                        return;
                    cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(ScanReceipt.this, "Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            },null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void updatePreview() {
        if(cameraDevice == null)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE,CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try{
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(),null,mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try{
            cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            //Check realtime permission if run higher API 23
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                },REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId,stateCallback,null);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {
            openCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startBackgroundThread();
        if(textureView.isAvailable())
            openCamera();
        else
            textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try{
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread= null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }

    private void askPermissions() {

        int permissionCheckStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        // we already asked for permisson & Permission granted, call camera intent
        if (permissionCheckStorage == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            //do what you want

        } else {

            // if storage request is denied
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage("You need to give permission to access storage in order to work this feature.");
                builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                builder.setPositiveButton("GIVE PERMISSION", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();

                        // Show permission request popup
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ScanReceipt.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                });
                builder.show();

            } //asking permission for first time
            else {
                // Show permission request popup for the first time
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ScanReceipt.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Activity_Scan_Receipt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Relvativelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ScanReceipt">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Add new receipt"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/snapPictureBtn"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/receiptscan" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/progressStatusText"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/receiptscan"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:text="Scan Receipt"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/snapPictureBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/progressStatusText"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Snap"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/receiptscan"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressStatusText">

                <TextureView
                    android:id="@+id/textureView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```