# android Camera2 Hit timeout for jpeg callback

Tags: android, android-camera

I am creating an app on android 5.0.2 using new camera API(camera2). The app is to   take a picture every 2.5 sec for 3 hours(4320 pictures in total). As you can see in the code below I coded repeating stuff with "timer" and no preview referring to  [Capture picture without preview using camera2 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003186/capture-picture-without-preview-using-camera2-api). I am using NEXUS7 2013 16G 5.0.2 for the test. It works fine for the beginning 200-300 pictures and failed with the following error message. The fail always starts with "E/RequestThread-1﹕ Hit timeout for jpeg callback!", it must trigger something. Would anyone help to get rid of this trigger? Or this is going to fixed in 5.1.0 if it is android bug??

```
03-30 15:46:04.472  11432-11432/com.example.android.camera2basic V/yo click﹕ ----   174 ---- click
03-30 15:46:05.026  11432-11537/com.example.android.camera2basic E/RequestThread-1﹕ Hit timeout for jpeg callback!
03-30 15:46:05.027  11432-11537/com.example.android.camera2basic W/CaptureCollector﹕ Jpeg buffers dropped for request: 173
03-30 15:46:05.076  11432-11480/com.example.android.camera2basic E/CameraDevice-JV-1﹕ Lost output buffer reported for frame 173
03-30 15:46:05.090  11432-11537/com.example.android.camera2basic W/LegacyRequestMapper﹕ convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
03-30 15:46:05.090  11432-11537/com.example.android.camera2basic W/LegacyRequestMapper﹕ Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
03-30 15:46:05.091  11432-11537/com.example.android.camera2basic W/LegacyMetadataMapper﹕ convertAfModeToLegacy - ignoring unsupported mode 4, defaulting to fixed
03-30 15:46:05.091  11432-11537/com.example.android.camera2basic W/LegacyRequestMapper﹕ convertRequestToMetadata - Ignoring android.lens.focusDistance false, only 0.0f is supported
03-30 15:46:05.098  11432-11537/com.example.android.camera2basic E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: RequestThread-1
Process: com.example.android.camera2basic, PID: 11432
java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
        at android.hardware.Camera.startPreview(Native Method)
        at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.RequestThreadManager.startPreview(RequestThreadManager.java:275)
        at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.RequestThreadManager.doJpegCapturePrepare(RequestThreadManager.java:288)
        at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.RequestThreadManager.access$1700(RequestThreadManager.java:61)
        at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.RequestThreadManager$5.handleMessage(RequestThreadManager.java:767)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Here is my code::

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

    Timer mTimer = null;
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private ImageReader imageReader;
    private Handler backgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread backgroundThread;
    private String cameraId;
    private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    private CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession;

    static int count = 0;
    static int count2 = 0;

    /**
     * Conversion from screen rotation to JPEG orientation.
     */
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button takePicture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.takepic);
    takePicture.setOnClickListener(onClickPicture);

    //(1) setting up camera but stop before camera createCaptureRequest
    setupCamera2();
}

private void setupCamera2() {
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);



    try {

        for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);


        //if (characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) != CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK) {
        if (characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) != CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
            continue;
        }

    StreamConfigurationMap configs = characteristics.get(
         CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);          


        this.cameraId = cameraId;

    manager.openCamera(this.cameraId, cameraStateCallback, backgroundHandler);

            Size[] sizes = configs.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);

        int   picWidth = 640;//1920;
            int   picHeight = 480;//1080;

        imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(picWidth, picHeight, ImageFormat.JPEG, 2);
        imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(onImageAvailableListener, backgroundHandler);
        }

    } catch (CameraAccessException | NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private final CameraDevice.StateCallback cameraStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(CameraDevice device) {
        cameraDevice = device;
    //(2) Camera capture session
        createCameraCaptureSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice cameraDevice) {}

    @Override
    public void onError(CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {}

};



    //private void createCaptureSession() {
private void createCameraCaptureSession() {
    List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new LinkedList<>();
    outputSurfaces.add(imageReader.getSurface());

    Log.v("-yo(2)-", "in createcameraCaptureSession now");

    try {

        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
        //cameraCaptureSession = session;
        cameraCaptureSession = session;
        //commented out to invoked from button 
        //createCaptureRequest();
        }

           @Override
       public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {}
        }, null);

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener onImageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        //createCaptureRequest();

    Log.v("yo ireader ","----   "+(count2++)+" ---- ireader");  

    //Image mImage = imageReader.acquireLatestImage();
        Image mImage = reader.acquireLatestImage();
        File mFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/yP2PTEST/0P2Pimage.jpg");

    Log.v("--yo--", "In ImageReader now writing to "+mFile);
    /////////////////////////////////////
            ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
            buffer.get(bytes);
            FileOutputStream output = null;
            try {
                output = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
                output.write(bytes);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                mImage.close();
                if (null != output) {
                    try {
                        output.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        ImageView curPic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Bitmap mCurrentBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFile.getPath());
        curPic.setImageBitmap(mCurrentBitmap); 
        }
    ///////////////////////////////////
    };



private void createCaptureRequest() {

    Log.v("-yo(3)-", "in createCaptureRequest now");

    try {

        CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        requestBuilder.addTarget(imageReader.getSurface());

        // Focus
        requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

        // Orientation
        //yo int rotation = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int rotation = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));

       // cameraCaptureSession.capture(requestBuilder.build(), camera2Callback, null);
        cameraCaptureSession.capture(requestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, null);

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


    CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback
            = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request,
                                       TotalCaptureResult result) {
            //showToast("JPEG Saved : ");
            //Log.v("yo save","- saved JPEG -");
            //unlockFocus();
        }
    };




    private Handler mMessageHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            if (this != null) {
                Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, (String) msg.obj, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };

    private void showToast(String text) {
        // We show a Toast by sending request message to mMessageHandler. This makes sure that the
        // Toast is shown on the UI thread.
        Message message = Message.obtain();
        message.obj = text;
        mMessageHandler.sendMessage(message);
    }



//------------------------------------------------------------//


    public View.OnClickListener onClickPicture = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


        /*-------  camera2   --------------*/
        mTimer = null;
        mTimer = new Timer(true);
        mTimer.schedule( new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /*------------------------*/
                mHandler.post( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    createCaptureRequest(); 
                    Log.v("yo click ","----   "+(count++)+" ---- click");
                }
                });

            }
            }, 1000, 2500);//1500,1600, 1800 etc
        };
    };

};
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I looked into source program of CAMERA2 API and found where the error message comes. 
JPEG_FRAME_TIMEOUT is currently 300ms, I guess it is so small and want to increase it. If anyone know how to do it, please let me know?

```
if (holder.hasJpegTargets()) {
                            doJpegCapture(holder);
                            if (!mReceivedJpeg.block(JPEG_FRAME_TIMEOUT)) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Hit timeout for jpeg callback!");
                                mCaptureCollector.failNextJpeg();
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I've had same issue with modified google sample.
After taking two pictures I got this error, so you just need to extend last parameter as much as you need, and it will work.

```
    imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(),ImageFormat.JPEG, 2);
```

But keep in mind this:
`@param maxImages` The maximum number of images the user will want to access simultaneously. This should be as small as possible to limit memory use. Once `maxImages` Images are obtained by the user, one of them has to be released before a new Image will become available for access through `{@link #acquireLatestImage()}` or `{@link #acquireNextImage()}`. Must be greater than 0.