# Android:Raw Image No Preview

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I want to take a raw image through the Camera2 API. There are plenty of guides for it, but none are done without a preview streamed to the screen.

I want to know if it is possible to code such that I can take **raw images** without a *preview*, perhaps a class I can instantiate and just call a method and get a `Image` or `byte[]`.

Comment: The camera API is built around preview stream. You can try to hide it from the end user by employing overlays or manipulating textures and surfaces, but any such solution may stop working on a non-tested device or after system upgrade

Comment: Ah, that's what I feared. Thanks anyways!

Comment: I think this question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003186/capture-picture-without-preview-using-camera2-api