# is it possible to capture raw image without preview using camera2

Tags: android, android-camera2

I tried to capture raw image without preview ,image showing blank

I tried capture  raw image with preview image displaying properly.

Note:both images are saved as .dng file using DngCreator

i tried to capture jpeg and yuv iamges without preview those are displaying properly

Comment: Have you  check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003186/capture-picture-without-preview-using-camera2-api

Comment: ya I checked that  but its working only for JPEG captures

Comment: capture without preview only working for jpeg images

Comment: capture without preview for raw image capture showing blank screen