# Taking photo in android

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, picturecallback

Hi I am developing my app with Camera functionality with SurfaceView.
I want to take picture when surface view created.

In my fragment's onCreateView method, initialized everything what I need.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_one_start_fragment, container, false);

        initWidgets(view);    
        return view;

    }
```

In initWidgets() method initialized the SurfaceView object as below

```
mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.game_action_surfaceview);
mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
```

In OnResume() method getting the surfaceHolder object.

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        safeCameraOpen(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);

    }
```

safeCameraOpen() I have followed the [Android Developer link](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html). Used the same code as mentioned.

The surfaceHolder.callback used as below

```
@Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        mCamera.startPreview();

    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        try {
//to set the picture orientation
            setCameraDisplayOrientation(getActivity(), findFrontFacingCameraID(), mCamera);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);


    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
    }
```

I want to take picture when the fragment loaded.

I have tried in OnViewCreated(),onResume() and onStart() lifecycle methods.
Within them I have used the following line

```
 mCamera.takePicture(null,null,mPictureCallback);
```

(mCamera object created and initialized in safeCameraOpen() method)

If I tried within the mentioned lifecycle methods, I am getting the following crash error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
            at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
            at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1266)
            at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1211)
            at com.gaming.fragment.GameOneStartFragment.snapPicture(GameOneStartFragment.java:76)
            at com.gaming.fragment.GameOneStartFragment.surfaceCreated(GameOneStartFragment.java:284)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:572)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
            at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:175)
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1897)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1019)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5725)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But, when I use the takePicture() method of Camera object inside a button click it capture the picture.

How can I do take picture without view click ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't call the startPreview method of Camera object.
I think you should call startPreview before take a picture.
In this case you didn't set the preview display:

```
try {
   camera.setPreviewDisplay(surface.getHolder());
} catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Check this answer: [How to take pictures from the camera without preview when my app starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684553/how-can-i-enable-my-android-app-to-take-pictures-from-the-camera-without-preview)

Comment: In surfaceChanged method  I did that.

Comment: I think the surfaceCreated method never invoked, because you did not set the preview display.

Comment: Can we take picture without touching any views?

Comment: I have checked/debugged and the SurfaceHolder callbacks are called perfectly.

Comment: In this case try to take photo after call startPreview.